# Text in the shape unconventional

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please look this [SAMPLE](http://cssdeck.com/labs/nfbhuxz8).

I want my text "Is The Best Team?" to be fully within a div and align to central.
Nothing comes out of the main div.

Any idea what I might be missing out please?

Comment: It is in the center of the div, but the top-right rounded corner is making it go out of its parent container.

You should use another aligning method or lower the radius of that corner

Comment: Yes, I understand. After you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Html:

```
<div class="badge"><div id='anotherDiv'>Is The Best Team?</div></div>
```

Css:

```
.badge {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  background: red;
}
#anotherDiv
{
  font-size:12px;
  padding-right:20%;
  padding-top:15%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your '.badge' class:

Use `border-top-right-radius: 50%` to make the text fit inside the div.

Or use: `vertical-align: bottom` to make the text go to the bottom of the parent element, then you can add some margin-bottom to the text, to make it look like its 'centered'.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that matters to me is the reaction orientation. Resize and change the curvature of the circle.
Text inside div maintain its position.